# Asterisk server shows peer UNREACHABLE for Kamailio sipper server. How do I diagnose the issue?

Tags: asterisk

Presently I have 4 sippers, 2 are working using OpenSer and 2 are not working using Kamailio.  I have inherited these servers.  There is an Asterisk server.  When I run sip show peer SIP_SER against one of the servers that is not functioning for test calls, it states Status: UNREACHABLE.  When I make test calls against it, I get Service Unavailable 503.  The asterisk server shows "Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber absent).

At this point, I'm just looking for how to diagnose what is happening here.  The OpenSer servers are connecting and successfully making test calls.